# Failing to pass variable data to View on PHP with Laravel 6.4

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started learning how to code with PHP with Laravel framework and for whatever reason this really simple code is giving me errors. I tried for hours to try to figure out why its not working, but simply can't find why.

I'm trying to pass a variable from web.php to welcome.blade.php.

web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function ()
{
    $tasks = [
        'Go to store',
        'Go to home',
        'Go to work'
    ];

    return view('welcome', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>My First Website</h1>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>
            <li><?= $task; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
@endsection
```

For whatever reason the compiler states that $tasks variable is not initialized in welcome.blade.php. If I use blade @foreach and @endforeach, it states that the $task one is not initialized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to pass the tasks in another way:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function ()
{
    $tasks = [
        'Go to store',
        'Go to home',
        'Go to work'
    ];

    return view('welcome', compact('tasks'));
});
```

And also, use blade syntax in the blade template files

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>My First Website</h1>

    <ul>
        @foreach ($tasks as $task)
            <li>{{ $task }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Comment: can you adjust your use of `compact` to not use a constant and use the string for the name instead?

Comment: It saves some code and still does the does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems alright.
But please use blade syntaxes in blade.html pages.

> Run these commands though maybe some cache issues.
>
> `php artisan cache:clear; php artisan view:clear; php artisan route:clear`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome', ['tasks' => ['Go to store', 'Go to home', 'Go to work']]);
});
<ul>
   @foreach($tasks as $task)
       <li>{{$task}}</li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

if you are still unsuccessful then try with this as well.

```
php artisan config:clear; php artisan config:cache
```